# The Ground Axiom for special statements of set theory

Tags: set-theory, forcing, continuum-hypothesis

The  Ground Axiom (GA),  introduced by Hamkins and Reitz, asserts that the universe is not a nontrivial set forcing extension of any inner model, and it is known that GA is consistent relative to ZFC. My question is somehow related to GA.

First a definition:

**Definition.** Let $\Phi$ be a statement of set theory which is independent of ZFC (or ZFC+large cardinals). Call $\Phi$  **forceable**, if there is a model $W$ of ZFC and a set of forcing conditions $P$ in $W$ such that $\Phi$ is true in the generic extensions of $W$ by $P$ (we allow the existence of large cardinals in $W$).

**Question.** 1) Is there a characterization of all forceable sentences $\Phi$ such that the following holds:

If $\Phi$ holds in $V$, then there some inner model $W$ of $V$ in which $\Phi$ fails, and such that $V$ is a set generic extension of $W$.

2) Can you give at least one natural statement $\Phi$ as in (1).

**Remark** (suggested by Sy Friedman).  In the paper "A Large $\Pi^1_2$ Set, Absolute for Set Forcings", Sy Friedman constructs a $\Pi^1_2$ formula $\phi$ which can have many solutions in a cardinal-preserving extension of $L$. $\phi$ also has the property that set-forcing will not add new solutions.
So no model in which $\phi$ has more than $\aleph_1$ solutions can be a set-generic extension of a model with only $\aleph_1$ solutions.

Also there are reals $r$ which are minimal over $L$ but which cannot be obtained by set forcing over $L$. Then in $V=L[r]$ the sentence $V=L$ fails, but there is no inner model $W$ of $V$ satisfying $V=L$ such that $V$ is a set forcing extension of $W$.

Answer (score 8):

In your definition, probably you intend that the forcing is nontrivial, since otherwise any consistent $\Phi$ would qualify via trivial forcing. Note also that your *forceable* terminology conflicts with the terminology used elsewhere, where an assertion $\sigma$ is *forceable* in a model $V$, if it holds in some set-forcing extension $V[G]$. This is the possibility modal operator $\Diamond\sigma$ of [The modal logic of forcing](http://jdh.hamkins.org/themodallogicofforcing/), whose dual $\Box\sigma$ asserts that $\sigma$ is *necessary*, that is, that $\sigma$ holds in all forcing extensions $V[G]$. Each of these operators is expressible in the first-order language of set theory. That is, $\Phi$ is forceable-in-your-sense if there is some model of set theory in which it is forceable.

Benedikt Löwe and I have also introduced the downward versions of these operators, where we say $\varphi$ is *downward possible* — let's write it as $\underline\Diamond\varphi$ here — if $\varphi$ holds in some ground model over which the universe was obtained by forcing. Although it is not obvious, the assertion, "there is an inner model $W$ for which $V=W[G]$ is a set-forcing extension and $W\models\varphi$" is first-order expressible in set theory. This kind of observation is the beginning of the subject known as [Set-theoretic geology](http://jdh.hamkins.org/set-theoreticgeology/). The dual notion $\underline\Box\varphi$, which asserts that $\varphi$ holds in all ground models, is similarly expressible. The situation of these modal operators in set theory is investigated in our paper [Moving up and down in the generic multiverse](http://jdh.hamkins.org/up-and-down-in-the-generic-multiverse/). In that paper, in order to determine the modal logic, we identify classes of statements, such as the *downward switches*, which can be turned on and off by going to deeper and deeper grounds, and the *downward buttons*, which are false in $V$ but true in some ground $W$ and all deeper grounds below $W$. The proofs required us to have large independent families of such buttons and switches, and other types of control statements.

Your statements $\Phi$ are similar to this kind of statement, but go just one step. Specifically, your statements $\Phi$ are precisely the statements for which $\Phi\to\underline\Diamond\neg\Phi$ holds.

I'm not sure what you want in terms of a "classification", but my point is that your property is first-order expressible in the language of set theory, even though it may appear to be second-order because of the quantification over inner models. Set-theoretic geology provides a first-order definable enumeration $W_r$ for $r\in V$ of the collection of all grounds $W_r$ of $V$, and so quantifying over grounds amounts to quantifying over the parameters $r$ used to define them and thus is a first-order quantifier. (You can see an account of the complexity of this definition in my recent paper [Superstrong and other large cardinals are never Laver indestructible](http://jdh.hamkins.org/superstrong-never-indestructible/).)

Comment: Dear Prof. Hamkins, thanks a lot for your interesting answer.